# program to print rectangle pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Need help developing a JavaScript program that accepts number as an input and then displays a rectangle of 3 columns wide and 5 rows tall using that digit.

```
Basically the output I want is as follows, 
555
55
55
555
```

the below is the code I have but i am not happy with hardcoding -

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
function rectangle() {
    console.log(input.value, input.value, input.value);
    console.log(input.value, input.value);
    console.log(input.value, input.value);
    console.log(input.value, input.value);
    console.log(input.value, input.value, input.value);
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: You mean fill rectangle using input digit. Right? If you have something in mind of how you will go about it, then I can help fill the pieces if required.

Comment: Even a pseudo code is good

Comment: @Jacob please see update above. Thanks

Comment: When you said "3 columns wide and 5 rows tall using that digit". Do you want the digit to be printed out to make the rectangle? Your example output is not a rectangle?

Comment: @Jacob if you look at the shape of the above output , It forms a rectangle.

Comment: Why does row 2 and 3 only have 2 digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are looking for is a 3x5 grid of an input digit, you can use this.

```js
function rectangle() {
  const input = document.getElementById("input").value

  let stringToDisplay = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      stringToDisplay += " " + input + " "
    }
    stringToDisplay += "</br>"
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = stringToDisplay
}
```

```html
<input id="input" onkeyup="rectangle()"> Enter input to be displayed
<div id="output" />
```

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I needed. Appreciate the  help

Answer (score 0):

I assumed 3 columns=30px
5 rows=50px

```js
var inp=document.getElementById("length");
var div=document.getElementById("theDiv");
inp.onchange=(e)=>{
  div.style.width=inp.value*3*10+"px";
  div.style.height=inp.value*5*10+"px";
  
}
```

```html
<input id="length" type="number"/>
<div id="theDiv" style="border:solid 1px black;width:0px;height:0px"></div>
```